# FLATHUB/FLATPAK Correct .repo File Configuration

Tags: flatpak

Anyone know the correct .repo config for flathub? I'm trying to yum install a newer version of flatpak and I keep getting the following:

> https://dl.flathub.org/repo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

My .repo config:

```
[flatpak-repo]
name=flathub
baseurl=https://dl.flathub.org/repo/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/Flathub-GPG-KEY
```